# Good internet map for wall poster

Tags: internet

We are looking for cool posters of an internet map for our office walls. We are a technology consulting company so that seems like the right kind of decoration. Since this is for a company office Server Fault seems like the right place to ask.

I have seen interesting network maps as conference shwag, but where do I buy them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try browsing the [CAIDA site](http://www.caida.org/home/). Making cool maps of the Internet is their job.

Comment: I feel dumb for not mentioning nmap's Icons of the Web: http://nmap.org/favicon/ since I got to see Fyodor show it off it in person.

Comment: The CAIDA map is quite old :)

Answer (score 4):

From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com):

***New!*** [Online Communities 2](http://xkcd.com/802/)

[image]

[Map of the Internet](http://xkcd.com/195/)

[image]

[Online Communities](http://xkcd.com/256/)

[image]

Both are available as posters from the [xkcd store](http://store.xkcd.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a bit tired of the ever present XKCD maps, so here are some more modern and interesting maps in A0 size:

Web Trends map modelled after Tokyo subway:
http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/wtm4/

The 140 most influential Twitter users, their #name #handle #category #influence #activity, when they first started and what they first said:
http://www.informationarchitects.jp/en/c140/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something nostalgic: http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/m.dodge/cybergeography//atlas/historical.html

Something a little more modern: http://personalpages.manchester.ac.uk/staff/m.dodge/cybergeography//atlas/geographic.html

More from google images: http://www.google.com/images?q=internet%20maps

Answer (score 0):

XKCD has two very nice internet maps: [IP space](http://xkcd.com/195/) and [online communities](http://xkcd.com/256/). It's not entirely fresh anymore, though.

Answer (score 0):

The [TeleGeography Global Internet Map](http://www.telegeography.com/telecom-maps/global-internet-map/index.html) is the best I've found, and it's up-to-date (2011), but it's extremely expensive ($250).